# How to email group/distrubtion instead of a wall of individuals when using a workflow?

Tags: designer-workflow, sharepoint-email, distribution-lists

It turns out I can't use email distribution lists in SP workflow (complicated), so I had to create SP Group and re-add all the recipients. However, I ran into several major nuances:

- Receipts are seeing a WALL of individuals in the "To:" line. In the past in Outlook it looked proper, like only the email distro was showing ex. "National List; Support; boss@company.com", etc.
- Many users are seeing duplicate emails because they are listed in several of these email groups.

Is there a solution to this?

P.S. 
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the SharePoint 2013/2016/Online workflow, you can't send an email to a untrusted account which means recipient is not a valid SharePoint User/Group.

You will see a warning if you want to add a group.
[image]

**To send an email to your distribution group you have to enable the Security group settings. And then you need to add this group to SharePoint site to make a valid SharePoint user.**

You can update the group setting from your Active Directory server.[image]

Comment: Would this work for clients that use Office 365 for SP and email? I only ask because our administrator said that "we'd have to recreate main group [email distribution list] and subgroups as office 365 Groups"

Comment: This works SharePoint Online (O365) site as well which is currently settings in our environment